# Can a person obtain a temporary reduced-cost Canadian passport to go shopping in the USA?

Tags: usa, passports, canadian-citizens

Can I just purchase a temporary passport to go shopping in the States? I don't go over that often so to spend $160 on a permanent passport is not worth it. I am a Canadian citizen would like go to Buffalo, NY to shop.

Comment: Nationality and intended journey please?

Comment: Canadian over to Buffalo N.Y

Comment: A temporary passport is not an option.  You can only get them when outside of Canada and after having applied for and paid for a regular passport.  See https://www.canada.ca/en/news/archive/2005/11/passport-canada-introduces-new-temporary-passport-canadians-abroad.html.  There is an *additional* fee for the temporary passport, making it a more expensive option, not less.  See http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/SOR-2012-253/FullText.html.

Comment: Will you be flying or driving? The requirements are different and you might not need a passport if you're driving.

Comment: $160 boils down to $16/year.

Comment: What research did you do on temporary passports before asking here? What did you find out?

Comment: @SimonRichter You pretty much have to renew it in the last year since many countries won't admit you with less than 6 months validity, and you want to do it at your own convenience, plus they eliminated the business passports so anyone who travels much will quickly run out of pages and have to pay for a new passport and carry the old one with any required visas . A bit of a scam, if you ask me.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany : Given the OP is only planning to use this document to travel Canada => USA a) they don't need six months extra validity; b) they aren't going to run out of pages for his visa. Also, you can renew a Canadian adult passport that has been expired for less than a year (so with careful timing of infrequent visits, you only require a new passport roughly every 11 years).

Comment: @phoog D'oh!  I particularly bad about that as I usually try to use gender-neutral language. [hangs head in shame]

Comment: @fattie you know what doesn't cost money? (barely?) Enhanced driver's licenses.  Quite a number of border states do them, including California even though they're not even on the Canadian border.

Comment: @MartinBonner I quite frequently make similar slips.

Comment: @Harper As far as I can tell California's attempt to pass an EDL law was vetoed in 2015.  Has there been a new law passed since then?  According to Wikipedia, US EDLs are available only in the states of [Michigan, Minnesota, New York, Vermont, and Washington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Drivers_License), which is less than half of the Canadian border states, even if you exclude Pennsylvania and Ohio, whose borders with Canada are in Lake Erie.

Comment: @phoog now that I'm double-checking, I'm not so sure.  What's changed is CA began to issue Real ID compliant drivers' licenses on January 22 2018, becuase surface transport from CA to anywhere else sucks, so TSA has CA over a barrel.  I thought they were one and the same but now I am learning it's possible to omit part of the Enhanced DL features resulting in a RealID license which is not viable as EnhDL.  SMH nothing is ever simple.

Comment: @Harper in particular, a US EDL can be issued only to a US citizen.  This is not true of regular driver's licenses, whether or not they comply with the requirements of the Real ID act.

Answer (score 54):

Accordin to [the Government of Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports/travel-documents-non-canadians/temporary-passport.html),

> The Canadian temporary passport is an eight-page, machine-readable
>   passport. It is:
>
> - issued by a Canadian mission
> - used for short-term situations
> - meant for urgent, proven travel situations or residency requirements
> - based on the decision of the Government of Canada passport/consular officer

This is evidently not appropriate for your application.

However, if you are a resident of Ontario (as I assume because you want to drive to Buffalo, NY), you can obtain an [Ontario enhanced driver license](https://www.ontario.ca/page/enhanced-drivers-licence) at a cost of $40, which is a valid travel document to visit the United States across a land or sea border. (It is not valid for air travel.)

Comment: I am from Alberta, some of my family lives in Ontario.  do you know if Alberta has this enhanced drivers license?

Comment: Furthermore, temporary passports are issued only outside of Canada; see https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports/travel-documents-non-canadians/document-types.html.  Furthermore, applicants for a temporary passport must already have applied and paid for a regular passport.  See https://www.canada.ca/en/news/archive/2005/11/passport-canada-introduces-new-temporary-passport-canadians-abroad.html

Comment: @ChrissyS Sorry. It doesn't look like Alberta issues them.

Comment: [Only Ontario, Quebec, Manitoba and BC have enhanced drivers licenses.](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/canadian-citizenship/proof/enhanced-drivers-license.html)

Comment: @DJClayworth: [And Quebec stopped offering them to new applicants in 2014.](http://montrealgazette.com/news/local-news/quebecs-permis-drivers-licence-to-be-phased-out)

Comment: Saskatchewan considered offering them, but felt that the demand wouldn't be sufficient given the incremental costs of producing them.  A pretty large percentage of Canadians carries a passport, and passport carriers wouldn't need to pay the difference, so the market is limited from the start.

Answer (score 36):

You've misunderstood [what a temporary passport is](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports/travel-documents-non-canadians/temporary-passport.html). It's not a short term "passport-lite" that you can get more cheaply and easily than a regular passport. Rather, it's an emergency replacement that you can get from a Canadian embassy abroad when your main passport has been lost, stolen or damaged, to complete your trip and get you back home.

Answer (score 16):

If you are a Canadian citizen and you will be driving from Canada to the USA, then according to the US CBP, [you do not need a passport](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/619/~/visiting-the-u.s.---documents-required-for-canadian-citizens-%2F-residents-%2F) to enter the USA.

Instead of a passport, CBP will also accept:

> Enhanced Driver's License/Enhanced Identification Card, NEXUS,
>   FAST/EXPRES and SENTRI enrollment cards.

Note though that if you are arriving by air, you will need a passport (or a NEXUS card when departing from a designated Canadian airport).

Comment: Nexus https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/nexus/how-apply

Comment: Sentri is for Mexico. FAST/Expres is for truck drivers (people bringing commercial quantities of goods over).

Comment: @Harper - that's a quote directly from the CBP web site. They say that a Canadian can use a SENTRI card to enter the USA.

Comment: @brhans You're correct.  Canadians generally don't get SENTRI (NEXUS includes Global Entry + SENTRI benefits) unless they live in the US near the Mexican border, and don't travel to the Canadian border (which is necessary for NEXUS interviews).

Comment: All the SENTRI enrollment centers are in the United States near the Mexican border, so that's not a practical option for the OP. Neither is an Enhanced Driver's license, as they live in Alberta. I do believe it's possible to get a NEXUS card without a passport, though at $50 for 5 years plus a trip to an enrollment center vs $160 for a 10-year passport that can be used worldwide, it's not necessarily the best option.

Comment: @ZachLipton - again - I didn't make this up - *it's a quote directly from the CBP web site* which I included in its entirety in the hope that this information would be useful to others than just the OP of this particular question. Only the first part of the *quote* may well be relevant and useful to the OP of this question. Maybe there are some Canadians out there who do have SENTRI cards (for whatever reason) - the CBP site says that they can use these cards to enter the USA and *does not specify that they may only do so when leaving Mexico*.

Comment: @brhans : I don't think people are suggesting that the information is false - just that it is misleading/unhelpful given the constraints of the OP.  If you added a paragraph like "Of those Enhanced DL is not available for Alberta residents, FAST is for commercial truck drivers, and SENTRI is basically for the American/Mexico border.  That leaves NEXUS as an option." I think everyone would be much happier.

Comment: exactly as @MartinBonner explained, while the information on here is quite correct, and admirably presented, it is **wholly incomplete**.  Looking at the **question title** two of the options listed, are: wrong.

Comment: "or resident": this is not true. As the page you link to notes, "Residents (PR) of Canada who are landed immigrants generally need a passport and visa to enter the United States, unless they are a citizen of a country eligible for the Visa Waiver Program (VWP). If they are a citizen of a country eligible for the VWP, they are only required to have their valid passport - coming by land."

Comment: Folks.... Answerer fairly quoted CBP's website.  I was more curious so I looked up each of the mechanisms.   I posted the comments merely to share the bounty.  Simply to benefit readers or make it easy for answerer to add the data if interested.  For my part, I aim to imply no criticism nor obligation.  I'm sorry if my helpful info made anyone think less of the answer!  #benice #agf

Comment: @ZachLipton If the OP is mostly just interested in traveling to the U.S., though, NEXUS might actually be a better option than a passport, as [it allows the use of Global Entry kiosks in the U.S. and NEXUS kiosks in Canada, as well as dedicated NEXUS lanes at land border crossings](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/nexus/benefits-nexus). Even if OP gets a passport, NEXUS is not a bad idea if they'll be crossing between the U.S. and Canada semi-frequently.

Comment: @MartinBonner A modest edit suggestion is probably in order.

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind as well that while the price is $160, that is a 10-year passport that you can travel to nearly every country in the world on.  You used to be able to travel to the US from Canada using your drivers license, however this is no longer the case. The **enhanced drivers license** is only available in select provinces and it only allows entry via land or sea, and you cannot use this while travelling by air.  A Canadian passport is a invaluable piece of ID and you can use it in Canada for any situation in which you need more than one piece of government issued photo ID. This is a situation that happens more often than you would think and the time it saves having a second piece of id when you really need it is almost worth the cost alone. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [NEXUS](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/nexus). $50 for 5 years and only lets you go between Canada and the US. You must visit an enrollment center in person for an interview.